# To check whether series is convergent or not

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to evaluate these two questions

$P_1$ : $n$th term is given by $$\frac{(n + 1 )^n}{n^{n+(3/2)}}$$

$P_2$: $n$th term is given by $$n^2x(1-x^2)^n,\quad 0< x < 1$$

For $P_1$ I tried root test and ratio test but it failed . For $P_2$, I tried root test , it worked and I got $\lim 1-x^2$ after doing routine ratio procedure .

I don't know how to proceed from here.Thanks for kind help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, write as
$$\left( \frac{n+1}{n} \right)^n \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$
and realize $[(n+1)/n]^n = (1+1/n)^n \to e$. Thus it should be easy to use a comparison test here. (Use the fact that $(1+1/n)^n \leq M$ for some number $M$.)

For the second, you want the limit of your root to be less than $1$ to conclude convergence. Well, you get $1-x^2$ as your limit with $0 < x < 1$. So is the limit less than one for these values of $x$?

Comment: Ah yes p1 was easy .Thanks

Comment: For p2 i get 0 lessthan x^2 less than 2 .how can i conclude